# Programmatically grant access to a restricted post in woocommerce membership

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to find a way to remove the post restriction programmatically with WooCommerce Memberships. Currently, my scenario is that the post is restricted until a future date, at which point it will be available to everyone. However, my client wants to give some non-members early access to the content before the public date by inputting an "access code".

I have created an ACF named "early_access_code" for the post and added a popup to cover the post if it is restricted. There is also an input for the user to enter the access code.

For example, let's say I have Post A and have set it to be restricted until next month, but I want to allow non-members early access if they have the access code "granted". The user goes to Post A, sees the popup informing them that access is restricted until next month, and can input the access code. Once they enter "granted", they should be able to view the post.

The problem I am facing is that I cannot find a WooCommerce hook or filter that allows me to override the restriction. Is this possible to do?

UPDATE:
I have managed to get access to the proper hook but now I need to know if it is possible to unrestricted a post from a hook / filter in the functions file.

here is my current code:

```
function check_restricted_access($data) {

    $post_id = get_queried_object_id();

    $early_access_code = get_field('early_access_code', $post_id);

    $early_access_granted = $_COOKIE['pm_early_access_granted'];

    if( ($early_access_code && $early_access_granted) && ($early_access_code === $early_access_granted)) {
        echo 'access has been granted';
    }

    if (   ! current_user_can( 'wc_memberships_view_delayed_post_content',    $post_id )
            || ! current_user_can( 'wc_memberships_view_restricted_post_content', $post_id ) ) {

        echo 'restricted '.  $post_id;
    } else {
        echo 'allowed: '.  $post_id;
    }
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'check_restricted_access');
```

Comment: Does woocommerce_grant_product_download_access do what you're looking for?

Comment: @Chipster Unfortunately that hook does not work.